# Laravel Eloquent relationship not working in restful api

Tags: php, rest, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a simple one to many relationship in eloquent database with two tables. They are working fine in my normal controllers. But when I use them in my Restful controller, it shows me error of Class 'App/TVChannel' not found. Everything is working fine in other controllers. Here are the model classes:

**TVChannel.php**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TVChannel extends Model {

protected $table = 'tv_channel';
protected $fillable = ['name', 'img', 'hex_color', 'total_views', 'user_id', 'created_ip'];

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}

public function dramas() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Dramas', 'channel_id');
}
}
```

**Dramas.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Dramas extends Model {

protected $table = 'dramas';
protected $fillable = ['name', 'img', 'total_views', 'channel_id', 'user_id', 'created_ip'];

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
}

public function channel() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TvChannel', 'channel_id');
}

public function episodes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Episodes', 'drama_id');
}}
```

Here is the code from my normal controller where i am using ajax request to load more dramas

```
 public function loadMoreDrama(Request $request) {
    $all_dramas = Dramas::latest()->limit(10)->offset($request->input('offset'))->get();
    if (count($all_dramas) > 0) {
        $ajaxString = '';
        foreach ($all_dramas as $drama) {
            $ajaxString .= '<li class="collection-item avatar" id="delete-drama-' . $drama->id . '">
                                <img src="' . asset($drama->img) . '" class="circle">
                                <span class="title" id="d-title-' . $drama->id . '">' . $drama->name . '</span>
                                <p id="d-forselect-' . $drama->id . '" selectid="' . $drama->channel->id . '">' . $drama->channel->name . '</p>
                                <a href="#" onClick="myddropdown(' . $drama->id . ')" "id="d_dropdown_menu_' . $drama->id . '" data-activates="d_dropdown_' . $drama->id . '" data-alignment="right" class="custom-dropdown waves-effect waves-circle red-text dropdown-button secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">more_vert</i></a>
                                <ul id="d_dropdown_' . $drama->id . '" class="dropdown-content">
                                    <li><a href="#" class="grey-text text-darken-4" onClick="updateDrama(' . $drama->id . ', \'' . $drama->img . '\')">Update</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="grey-text text-darken-4" onClick="deleteDrama(' . $drama->id . ', \'' . $drama->img . '\')">Delete</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>';
        }
        return Response::json([
                    'success' => true,
                    'msg' => $ajaxString
        ]);
    } else {
        return Response::json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'msg' => 'No Drama to show'
        ]);
    }
}
```

And here is that function where i am getting that error:

```
public function getLatestDramas(Request $request)
{
    $drama = Dramas::latest()
        ->limit(10)
        ->offset($request->input('offset'))
        ->get();
    if ($drama->count() > 0) {
            $channels = array();
        foreach($dramas as $d){
            $channels[]= $d->channel;
        }
        return $this->export(TRUE, $channels);
    } else {
        return $this->export(FALSE, 'no drama to show right now');
    }

}
```

Please tell me where i am going wrong or what more should i do.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add namespace to models?

Comment: in your Dramas.php channel() relationship has wrong class name it should be TVChannel instead of TvChannel consider v is different and as class names are case sensitive, you should include it as TVChannel::class if they are in same namespace otherwise just use class so you can get correct reference.

Comment: @MarekSkiba added namespaces

Comment: @Sam wow .. i didn't notice the simple error. Thankyou for this, it resolved my problem. Please post it as an answer so i can select as correct answer. Thankyou once again.

Comment: you are most welcome.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in Drama.php file TvChannel should be TVChannel, since the model name is TVChannel.
change

`public function channel() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TvChannel', 'channel_id');
}`

to

`public function channel() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TVChannel', 'channel_id');
}`

The previous code may work on Windows but won't work on Linux since Linux is case sensitive.